# Skip execution if exception thrown

Tags: java, exception

I am stuck on something very basic. In our game we have a leveleditor/loader that can fetch levels via URL. Now if the URL points to a nonexistant file the editor should refuse to load the level and simply stay in its currentlevel, I am just struggling with the basic code.

```
private void loadLevel(URL url) {
    Scanner in = null;
    try {
        in = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                url.openStream())));
        readLine(in);
        in.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Essentially, if `FileNotFound` is thrown (or any other) `readLine(in)` should NOT proceed. All kinds of NPE if it does.

Comment: So when the exception is thrown, what action do you wish should happen?

Comment: Right after the code. readLine() executes even if an exception is thrown.

Comment: @ Chetter Hummin, no action.

Comment: it wont execute, java has it that way only.

Comment: I have been looking for half an hour, I am pretty sure the levelEditor is the only object that calls the readLine.

Comment: Found it, resourcemanager was calling a bad URL in a background thread. A stupid question in hindsight.

Answer (score 2):

```
private void loadLevel(URL url) {
    Scanner in = null;
    try {
        in = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                url.openStream())));
        /*if(in!=null){
            readLine(in);
            in.close();
        }*/
        readLine(in);
        in.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

EDIT: After @LuiggiMendoza's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Use `throws` and `finally`. Let the calling function handle it. I haven't tested it, but this sort of thing is the idea...

```
private void loadLevel(URL url) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner in = null;
    try {
        in = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                url.openStream())));
        if (in == null) throw new FileNotFoundException();
        readLine(in);
    }
    finally {
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the context of one single thread, if this line below throws exception, the next line of code will not execute. If you think your code is doing otherwise, it might be another thread doing it / some other code

```
in = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            url.openStream())));
```